# Confidence Interval for Mean with Non-Normal Data

Tags: confidence-interval, mean, bootstrap, normality-assumption

I have a small sample of 19 observations, with a mean of 8.105 and sd of 6.064. I want to calculate a 95% CI for the mean. My data is not normally distributed, according to the Q-Q plot. Assuming normality, I get a CI of [5.183,11.028]. I tried calculating a CI using bootstrap, but I am not sure I did it okay. The result was [5.372,10.84]. Does it makes sense that it's narrower? Is there another method of doing it (maybe using LOG transformation).

My R code is:

```
library("mosaic")
xbar = mean(X)
trials = do(1000) * mean(resample(X))
histogram(~mean, data = trials, col="gray")
se = sd(~ mean , data = trials)
xbar - 1.96*se
xbar + 1.96*se
```

Thank you.

Comment: One more thing, how many samples should I take? I know that the default in Stata for example, is 50. I took 1000, too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimating a margin of error using methods that are based on central limit theorem (CLT) is inappropriate and suffer deficiencies. Bootstrapping is the appropriate method in your case. You could try package `'boot'` or package '`bootstrap`' in R.